# Rails Query transformation from 3.2.12 to 4.2.0 doesn't return anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in rails 3.2.12 I've got this query and it Worked fine:

```
lesson.questions.find :all, :order => DB_RANDOM, :limit => limit
```

I've made this, But I don't retrieve anything

```
lesson.questions.find().order("DB_RANDOM").limit(:limit).all
```

I've only got this back:

```
2015-05-10 00:55:52 INFO undefined method `find' for "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>":String
```

also had this:

```
lesson.questions.find().order("DB_RANDOM").limit(:limit).all
```

But then I got this:

```
 undefined method `question' for #<Lesson:0x00000006a8b550>
```

what would be the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to create that relation in Rails 4 is:

```
lesson.questions.order(DB_RANDOM).limit(limit)
```

On that relation you can run methods like `all`, `count` or `each`...

Comment: I've tried it this way `lesson.questions.order(DB_RANDOM)`... but its empty

Comment: Did you fry it with `.all` at the end? Can you please post how `DB_RANDOM` and the database association `questions` are defined in your model`?

Answer (score 2):

In rails 4 you can get random in postgres by

```
lesson.question.order("RANDOM()").limit(limit).all

              or 
lesson.question.limit(limit).order("RANDOM()").all
```

placing limit before and after yields the same result.

if you are using mysql then use the RAND function.

```
lesson.question.order("RAND()").limit(limit).all
```